# Image file changes content after saving with MS Paint

Tags: image, paint

I have an image, which is 10KB. I opened it by MS Paint and do nothing but pressing Ctrl + S. The file's size increased to 12KB.
I check the content of the file before and after saving by MS Paint and it turns out there are some differences:

[image]

Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of investigation, I found out that when open and save the image the second time by MS Paint, it automatically converts the image from 24 bit depth format to 32 bit depth format.